# Retrofit Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

Learning how to use Retrofit in my Android App, getting following error:
Please help if you can. Thank you,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

here is my code: Please help if your able too:

```
public void clickButton(View view){
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    drawDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.drawDate);

    LotteryAPI.Factory.getIstance().getLottery().enqueue(new Callback<Lottery>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Lottery> call, Response<Lottery> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getting Draw Date");
            Log.d(TAG, "Draw Date is: " + response.body().getDrawDate());
            String DRAW_DATE = response.body().getDrawDate();
            drawDate.setText("DRAW_DATE");
            Log.d(TAG, "done setting Draw Date");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Lottery> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Failed",  t.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "At onFailure - Something Failed!!");
            Log.d(TAG, "error is: " + t.getCause());

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
String BASE_URL = "https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json/";

@GET("?$$app_token=xxxxxxGtxKw3s6gurSxxxxxx")
Call<Lottery> getLottery();


class Factory {
    public static LotteryAPI service;

    public static LotteryAPI getIstance() {
        if (service == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();
            service = retrofit.create(LotteryAPI.class);
            return service;
        } else {
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my POJO:

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Lottery {

    @SerializedName("draw_date")
    @Expose
    private String drawDate;
    @SerializedName("mega_ball")
    @Expose
    private String megaBall;
    @SerializedName("multiplier")
    @Expose
    private String multiplier;
    @SerializedName("winning_numbers")
    @Expose
    private String winningNumbers;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The drawDate
     */
    public String getDrawDate() {
        return drawDate;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param drawDate
     *     The draw_date
     */
    public void setDrawDate(String drawDate) {
        this.drawDate = drawDate;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The megaBall
     */
    public String getMegaBall() {
        return megaBall;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param megaBall
     *     The mega_ball
     */
    public void setMegaBall(String megaBall) {
        this.megaBall = megaBall;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The multiplier
     */
    public String getMultiplier() {
        return multiplier;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param multiplier
     *     The multiplier
     */
    public void setMultiplier(String multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The winningNumbers
     */
    public String getWinningNumbers() {
        return winningNumbers;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param winningNumbers
     *     The winning_numbers
     */
    public void setWinningNumbers(String winningNumbers) {
        this.winningNumbers = winningNumbers;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure what am doing wrong..

Comment: Retrofit is failing to map the incoming json to your Lottery class. Post the json and you'll get some help.

Comment: here is the Link to the JSON Data, https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json?$$app_token=O1pR7hGtxKw3s6gurSXXkyy7V

Comment: [{"draw_date":"2016-10-04T00:00:00.000","mega_ball":"01","multiplier":"05","winning_numbers":"18 29 30 54 66"}
,{"draw_date":"2016-09-30T00:00:00.000","mega_ball":"09","multiplier":"05","winning_numbers":"21 30 47 50 57"}
,{"draw_date":"2016-09-27T00:00:00.000","mega_ball":"04","multiplier":"04","winning_numbers":"14 16 26 53 72"}
,{"draw_date":"2016-09-23T00:00:00.000","mega_ball":"14","multiplier":"03","winning_numbers":"01 05 08 25 62"}
]

Comment: That is a sample of the JSON DATA Ivan, thanks again, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the structure of POJO class structure, because as i can see your json string is an array which contain objects. You have to make to POJO classes:

```
class Lottery {
  private String draw_date, mega_ball, multiplier, winning_numbers;

public Lottery() {}

public String getDraw_date() {
    return draw_date;
}

public void setDraw_date(String draw_date) {
    this.draw_date = draw_date;
}

public String getWinning_numbers() {
    return winning_numbers;
}

public void setWinning_numbers(String winning_numbers) {
    this.winning_numbers = winning_numbers;
}

public String getMega_ball() {
    return mega_ball;
}

public void setMega_ball(String mega_ball) {
    this.mega_ball = mega_ball;
}

public String getMultiplier() {
    return multiplier;
}

public void setMultiplier(String multiplier) {
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
}

}
```

You also have to change the following line into LotteryAPI interface from

```
Call<Lottery> getLottery();
```

to

```
Call<List<Lottery>> getLottery();
```

Then inside onResponse() callback you should iterate through the LotteryObj list

```
 public void clickButton(View view){
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    drawDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.drawDate);

    LotteryAPI.Factory.getIstance().getLottery().enqueue(new Callback<List<Lottery>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Lottery>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.e(TAG, response.body()+"");
            for (Lottery lt : response.body()) {
                Log.e(TAG, lt.getDraw_date());
                Log.e(TAG, lt.getMega_ball());
                if (lt.getMultiplier() != null) Log.e(TAG, lt.getMultiplier());
                Log.e(TAG, lt.getWinning_numbers());
            }
                Log.d(TAG, "getting Draw Date");
```

//                    Log.d(TAG, "Draw Date is: " +   response.body().getDrawDate());
//                String DRAW_DATE = response.body().getDrawDate();
                  drawDate.setText("DRAW_DATE");
                  Log.d(TAG, "done setting Draw Date");
            }

```
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Failed",  t.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "At onFailure - Something Failed!!");
            Log.d(TAG, "error is: " + t.getCause());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Tsiro, I made the changes, getting error on the LotteryObj, done know where is called from,

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: can i send you my complete project some how, or some kind of webex..lol

Comment: when i copy and replace my pojo with the pojo you have created, getting lotteryObj error like it doesn't know about it

Comment: upload your project on Github if you have an account

Comment: same when i replace the response code as well,

Comment: will do one sec

Comment: Tsiro, here is the github link, thank  you https://github.com/jsalmond/GetInternetStuff.git

Comment: sorry its uploading, one min

Comment: i 'll give it a try right away..

Comment: Tsiro, the code is uploaded to Github thank you https://github.com/jsalmond/GetInternetStuff.git

Comment: Than you Tsiro, let me know what I need to do, or when i should download the edited code, thank you again,, I really needed the help,, be 4 days of googling,  before i asked for help

Comment: the problem is that Gson converter expects your json to be an object but it finds an array...you should change the structure of your json into the following {"list":[{"draw_date":"2016-10-04T00:00:00.000","mega_ball":"01","multiplier":"05","winning_numbers":"18 29 30 54 66"},{}...]} and the above code will work fine

Comment: should i recreate the pojo with the updated json? and add the changes you said before?

Comment: you only have to update your json structure...POJO classes contain the structure posted above

Comment: update your json and tell me to give it a try

Comment: can you upload it to github, send link, if you dont mine

Comment: ok just inform me when you update your json

Comment: am trying to use a json to pojo converter online its not taking the syntax trying to fix it

Comment: you do not need to do it...just change https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json/ json structure as i proposed and let me know

Comment: now am lost..lol can you please post a screen shot of what i need to change the code too, or upload the code to github if you dont mine

Comment: my friend i found a solution..i update my answer

Comment: am lost on what you would like me to change in the code,, sorry just started coding 6 months now

Comment: let me look at the updated answer

Comment: the answer said edit 1 hour ago, which answer did you update, my friend.. :)

Comment: do you mine upload a sample app to the github with the code

Comment: try it and let me know

Comment: can you email me jsalmond@jtecx.com

Comment: ok, i see the code updated, let me try

Comment: code good so far, the only line of code it doesnt like is: response.body()) under onResponse

Comment: underline red line: foreach not applicable to type

Comment: check my updated answer...

Comment: looking to see what did you change, point it out

Comment: Call<List<Lottery>> call, Response<List<Lottery>> response inside onResponse

Comment: ok, taking a look now

Comment: override doesn't like it,

Comment: we are so close,, crazy

Comment: thank you for hanging in there with me, were u from?

Comment: am in North NJ, USA

Comment: Greece...ok now just remove all the code from clickButton method inside MainActivity and paste the updated answer code...

Comment: nice to meet you Tsiro, ok doing it now

Comment: is everything ok?

Comment: no, red lines, trying to work it out

Comment: override said not overriding supper class

Comment: have you changed LotteryAPI line as i suggested?

Comment: gray it out, do you mind, uploading a github

Comment: just give me a sec

Comment: still working it out, buy yes, i have copy and paste the code to make sure i type it correctly

Comment: https://github.com/tsironis13/InternetStuff.git

Comment: ok, am standing by

Comment: great, let me look

Comment: copying the code now

Comment: ok my friend just let me know

Comment: i will, downloading build tools 23.02 android studio is doing its thing, waiting

Comment: still downloading, build tools, for some reason internet got little slow,

Comment: ok take your time..

Comment: did u see my email address, you should email some time

Comment: ok, no problem...

Comment: retrofit seems straight forward on the code part, but, hard to debug issues

Comment: have you managed it?

Comment: i clicked on answered, because you have worked so hard to help me, soon as i get my android studio updated with the build tools and other stuff am going to open the code

Comment: just my luck, taking for ever to download the build tools,, omg..lol

Comment: no prob..it was trivial to me...happy to help others...if it works, you could also up vote my answer..have a nice day

Comment: going to vote the answer now!!

Comment: done, running app now,, fingers crossed!!

Comment: WOW..WOOW..WOW..,, It worked!!!! Tsiro,, You are the best!!! it worked!!!

Comment: Thank you so much Tsiro,, I am sure I would not have figured out the problem on my own, I spent days already googling and searching to find the answer, and soon as you came forward,, you fix my issue, I want to say thank you, if you was here, I would buy you few drinks,, thank you soo much again,

Comment: y are welcome my friend..do not forget to up vote my answer :)

Comment: trying to up vote the answer, said that i have less than 15 points are recorded but now shown publicly

Comment: up vote is recorded but not shown publicly because i have less than 15 points

Comment: if you have any cisco questions, am the man to ask, am a Cisco CCIE Security, just learning to code. thanks Tsiro

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the endpoint is returning a list of your Lottery class items and you are asking Retrofit to map the response to a single Lottery item.

Try changing `Call<Lottery> getLottery();` to `Call<List<Lottery>> getLottery();`. You will also need to change it in your Retrofit call definition.

Comment: going to give it a try now, ty Ivan will give update once done

Comment: Ivan, what do you mean i need to change it in my call definition? can you show me what needs to change in the Retrofit call definition, thanks

Comment: Ivan i changed it in the Retrofit call as well error

Comment: @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Lottery>> call, Response<Lottery> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getting Draw Date");
                Log.d(TAG, "Draw Date is: " + response.body().getDrawDate());
                String DRAW_DATE = response.body().getDrawDate();
                drawDate.setText("DRAW_DATE");
                Log.d(TAG, "done setting Draw Date");
            }

Comment: Ivan,  can you please take a look i uploaded the code to github

Comment: github code, https://github.com/jsalmond/GetInternetStuff.git

Comment: @JtecX I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/jsalmond/GetInternetStuff/pull/1) to your repository that implements the fix proposed by Ivan. This fixes your issue, and is the correct answer.

Comment: Awesome, you saved my day. Works perfectly